# UWP - Combination of node modification and page interaction on Web

Tags: c#, html, uwp

I am trying to accomplish some URL scraping from a webpage, however the URL's are only inserted into the webpage whenever a button is clicked. I have tried using HtmlAgilityPack however was unsuccessful as interaction with buttons is not possible. I have also tried using the WebView and HttpClient however none have which have been successful.

I am essentially just trying to accomplish the following in C# UWP:

- Simulate button click
- Get new HTML source

in that order.

Comment: I did not understand what you said about 'however the URL's are only inserted into the webpage whenever a button is clicked. '. Please provide more information about your requirement.

Comment: So whenever the page is initially loaded the links are not present however whenever a button is pressed the html document is reloaded (the page is not) and has the links in it.

Comment: Please check if my understanding was correct. You have a html page and it contains some hypelinks and a button. These links are not displayed at first, when you click the button, these links show there?